# How can I programmatically check to see if the Windows desktop setting "Auto arrange icons" is enabled or disabled using C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

How can I programmatically check to see if the Windows desktop setting "Auto arrange icons" is enabled or disabled using C#?

I have seen examples of arranging desktop icons but I actually want to check to see if the setting is enabled or disabled.

From what I have read in related questions, there is a registry setting and a group policy setting, but I would have thought there would have been a safer way to determine this using Win32 calls and it is a Win32 call I am looking for but I'm not sure what call I need to make.

As I'm writing an application in C# I would prefer it if a C# code example could demonstrate getting this value.

Preferably I would like something that works from Windows Vista to Windows 10 and above.

Comment: Registry is the best choice. And you can access it via C#.

Comment: Is that the safest method though as the registry setting values are not guaranteed to keep the same name or stay in the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the desktop programmatically for various flags including "auto arrange"; this is safer than using the registry as it's documented and supported.

This can be done using the [`IShellView::GetCurrentInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774831(v=vs.85).aspx) method. This function fills out a [`FOLDERSETTINGS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773308(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. To see if auto arrange is turned on, check the state of the `FWF_AUTOARRANGE` flag in the `fFlags` member (a full list of flags can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762508(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Below is C++ code to obtain the desktop's `IShellView` interface (taken from [Raymond Chen's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933)). You can probably convert this to C# fairly easily.

```
void FindDesktopFolderView(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
 CComPtr<IShellWindows> spShellWindows;
 spShellWindows.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows);

 CComVariant vtLoc(CSIDL_DESKTOP);
 CComVariant vtEmpty;
 long lhwnd;
 CComPtr<IDispatch> spdisp;
 spShellWindows->FindWindowSW(
     &vtLoc, &vtEmpty,
     SWC_DESKTOP, &lhwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH, &spdisp);

 CComPtr<IShellBrowser> spBrowser;
 CComQIPtr<IServiceProvider>(spdisp)->
     QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser,
                  IID_PPV_ARGS(&spBrowser));

 CComPtr<IShellView> spView;
 spBrowser->QueryActiveShellView(&spView);

 spView->QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
}
```

Comment: Has anybody ported this to C# and can share the code? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77958389/356726