# How can I disable "Auto arrange icons" of the Desktop view in C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I am using `PostMessage` to query and set the DESKTOP icon positions. Unfortunately this is only possible if the `auto arrange` setting is disabled.

This article explains how to disable it in C++. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933

This question [How can I programmatically check to see if the Windows desktop setting "Auto arrange icons" is enabled or disabled using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35807565/356726) has exactly the same code as answer, **but also ONLY in C++**. I do not find it that easy to port this code to C#. The question of 2016 has **NO** C# answer.

I have tried to use `Windows-API-CodePack-NET`, but I fail to get the Desktop view so I can set the flags. The API seems to have all the classes and flags, but I fail to get to the view. For instance `IShellWindows` does NOT SEEM to exist in the code pack.

Getting the handle for the view is explained here: [Get handle to desktop / shell window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8364758/356726) But I need to get the COM pointer like `CComPtr<IShellView>`.

Also his complete C# solution with source code does **only** work for me with "Auto arrange" disabled. Interesting he does not mention this constraint, might be it did not exist back then or it is something specific in my case. Solution to set icons: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639486/Save-and-restore-icon-positions-on-desktop

Allegedly it is also possible to disable the alignment by a message, but again I could not get it working. One reference e.g. [Arranging desktop icons with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24965672/356726)

```
IntPtr foo = CWindow.GetDesktopWindow();
CWindow.SendMessage(listViewPtr, (uint)LVM_Message.LVM_ARRANGE, (nint)LVA_Message.LVA_ALIGNTOP, 0);
CWindow.SendMessage(foo, (uint)LVM_Message.LVM_ARRANGE,(nint)LVA_Message.LVA_ALIGNTOP, 0);
```

Any idea how I can set the folder flags for the Desktop View? Get `spView`, C# version.

```
spView->Set­Current­Folder­Flags(FWF_AUTO­ARRANGE | FWF_SNAP­TO­GRID, 0)
```

[image: Context menu]

---

Ref:

- [Arranging desktop icons with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24965672/356726)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966096/356726
- Question at sharpshell: https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/issues/400

Comment: You have already discovered the correct way to find the positions of desktop items. Why do you insist on sending messages (and changing global settings)? Just use the supported interface already.

Comment: Because I am too stupid to use the interface in C#. Once I know how I can use the interface in C#, I'd be glad to use. Unfortunately I have also not seen any answer which would tell me how to convert the C++ solution. Exactly this is my problem here.

Comment: You can use the [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) code generator to get the COM interfaces translated to C#. The rest of the transliteration is pretty much mechanical, I guess. I don't do .NET.